# Lightweight RESTful Java Framework

Tags: java, rest

I have been looking into RESTful web services in Java and most of the approaches I have found look to be rather bloated. These include approaches from NetBeans, Spring 3, and EJB using Singletons.

I may be wrong so please feel free to correct me but these all 'feel' like very complicated solutions to a relatively simple problem.

Can anyone suggest a very simple and lightweight approach to doing RESTful webservices in java?

I am not convinced MVC is necessary on the back end for these, instead I am looking at doing clean vertical slices.

I will not need persistence unless it can be wired to mongoDB - so I don't need any ORM mapping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/), the summary on the website said what has to be said about.

> Developed by Yammer to power their JVM-based backend services,
>   Dropwizard pulls together **stable**, **mature** libraries from the Java
>   ecosystem into a **simple**, **light-weight** package that lets you focus on
>   getting things done.
>
> Dropwizard has out-of-the-box support for sophisticated **configuration,
>   application metrics, logging, operational tools**, and much more,
>   allowing you and your team to ship a production-quality HTTP+JSON web
>   service in the shortest time possible.

I used it for a simple app recently, and it proved to be really quick and easy to get started and use it until the app was finished.

Comment: Thanks for this. It is more what I am looking for. While the extras might be considered bloat, its not bloat associated with just getting the service operational. Its metrics and the like. This looks to be the best option for me and what I am looking to do.

Comment: Dropwizard link is dead, can you replace it please?

Comment: This is the link for Dropwizard: https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/getting-started.html

Answer (score 9):

Just to throw another option into the mix, check out [Spark](http://www.sparkjava.com/):

> A Sinatra inspired micro web framework

For Java.

Haven't used it personally, but it looks promising and I'm definitely going to check it out.

And, no, I am not affiliated with Spark in any way.

Comment: I'd recommend Javalin (https://github.com/tipsy/javalin) over Spark nowadays. It started as a fork of Spark, but has outgrown it.

Answer (score 8):

I've used CXF and Jersey for JAX-RS for creating RESTful web services. It was quite easy to create/deploy a RESTful service using either of them. I find the documentation was adequate to start up.

Comment: From my research I am going with dropWizard in spite of the good answer here. CXF and Jersey are certainly good choices, I am going with dropWizard (which leverages Jersey anyhow). Thanks for the input. Either CXF or Jersey would have met my needs as well.

Answer (score 3):

You might check out http://www.restlet.org/.  Another option would be to write a simple servlet to handle the requests, especially if this is a small project.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the [Apache Httpcomponents](http://hc.apache.org/) package. With that, you can have a Restful web service pretty easy.

There is an example of [non-blocking, asynchronous](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpServer.java) HTTP server, or [old style, blocking one](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpServer.java).

Another advantage is that this does not need any application servers, so you can just start your application, and there you go. If you don't need the power of a Servlet container, or Java EE, this seems ot be a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For "data based" RESTful services you are probably right about your assumption on MVC...you want some JSON to come back from URLs.

For true RESTful services (based on Hypermedia) w/ custom mediatype formats..MVC plays really nice as as the views become your media format templates.  This is especially true if you use HTML/XML as your base media format.

Comment: Thanks, I am very knew to the whole topic.